# How to track requests and exceptions within the Azure WebApp application

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-application-insights

We are using `Application Insights SDK` for our `Azure WebApp` application with Azure SQL Database and Azure Storage. Which Azure Service we can use to track time specific code requests and exceptions within the application?

Comment: This does not answers your question, but you can see some log files in Kudu. Navigate to https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net to access Kudu for your app, then Debug Console > PowerShell > LogFiles.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by time-specific code requests and exception from your OP ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Application Insights SDK, you can use it to track requests, exceptions, dependencies etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

The application insights SDK provides many methods for logging, so you can use built-in method like TrackException, TrackTrace, Trackxxx to track. Details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json#reporting-exceptions-explicitly).